# Using trycatch in a nested for loop

Tags: r

I'm unable to include a `trycatch` in a for loop that contains multiple functions. The inner most loop is where I would like for it to just skip over for any error that occurs. The multiple items within the `print` are to represent the number of functions I have but in reality I have much more. The error for the script itself is a notation issue. After every function it asks for a comma. That doesn't seem right.

Here is more or less what my script looks like. I'm having trouble replicating the notation issue. My script itself works without the trycatch but I wanted it there in the event of situation. Can trycatch work with multiple functions?

```
g <- c('a','b')
f <- list('a' = list("AB","CD"), 'b' = list("BA","BB"))

for (z in g){
test_list <- x[[f]]
  
for(y in test_list){
  tryCatch(
    print(
      x = "BA"
      pz = paste(x,"test"))
    , error = function(e){
    message('haha you mf',e)},
    warning = function(w){
      message("this is your warning",w)},
    finally = {message("skipped sub before ",f)
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: There are syntax problems with the code you posted. Are you trying to call `print()` with named parameters `x` and `px`? If so you need a comma between the parameters. Or what are you trying to do there? If you want to run more than one statement in the try catch, wrap the statements in brances `{}`, not `print()`. you also have `test_list <- x[[f]]` but `x` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @MrFlick horrible reprex made, but i think you answered my question. As long as the rest of the statements are in brances I should be fine